# Python: Faster regex replace

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a large set of large files and a set of "phrases" that need to be replaced in each file.
The "business logic" imposes several restrictions:

- Matching must be case-insensitive
- The whitespace, tabs and new lines in the regex cannot be ignored

My solution (see below) is a bit on the slow side. How could it be optimised, both in terms of IO and string replacement?

```
data = open("INPUT__FILE").read()
o = open("OUTPUT_FILE","w")
for phrase in phrases: # these are the set of words I am talking about
        b1, b2 = str(phrase).strip().split(" ")
        regex = re.compile(r"%s\ *\t*\n*%s"%(b1,b2), re.IGNORECASE)
        data = regex.sub(b1+"_"+b2,data)
o.write(data)
```

**UPDATE**: 4x speed-up by converting all text to lower case and dropping `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: wow.  impressive change with/out case.

Comment: you might try `re.compile(r"(%s)\s*(%s)"%(b1,b2))` and `regex.sub("\1_\2", data)` - no idea if it will be faster.

Comment: also, if you followed my advice about `\s*`, change it to `(?: |\t |\n)*` - that might avoid issues with unicode that are all i can think of to explain the case effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could avoid recompiling your regexp for every file:

```
precompiled = []
for phrase in phrases:
    b1, b2 = str(phrase).strip().split(" ")
    precompiled.append(b1+"_"+b2, re.compile(r"%s\ *\t*\n*%s"%(b1,b2), re.IGNORECASE))

for (input, output) in ...:
    with open(output,"w") as o:
        with open(input) as i:
            data = i.read()
            for (pattern, regex) in precompiled:
                data = regex.sub(pattern, data)
            o.write(data)
```

it's the same for one file, but if you're repeating over many files then you are re-using the regexes.

disclaimer: untested, may contain typos.

[**update**] also, you can simplify the regexp a little by replacing the various space characters with `\s*`.  i suspect you have a bug there, in that you would want to match `" \t "` and currently don't.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable thing to do. In practice, the processing time per file went down from 10.5 to 9.9 seconds.

Comment: i realised why this doesn't help - the regexps are cached.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in 1 pass by using a B-Tree data structure to store your phrases. This is the fastest way of doing it with a time-complexity of `N O(log h)` where N is the number of characters in your input file and h is the length of your longest word. However, Python does not offer an out of the box implementation of a B-Tree.

You can also use a Hashtable (dictionary) and a replacement function to speed up things. This is easy to implement if the words you wish to replace are alphanumeric and single words only.

```
replace_data = {}

# Populate replace data here
for phrase in phrases:
    key, value = phrase.strip().split(' ')
    replace_data[key.lower()] = value

def replace_func(matchObj):
    # Function which replaces words
    key = matchObj.group(0).lower()
    if replace_data.has_key(key):
        return replace_data[key]
    else:
        return key

# Original code flow
data = open("INPUT_FILE").read()
output = re.sub("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", replace_func, data)
o = open('OUTPUT_FILE', 'w')
o.write(output)
o.close()
```

Comment: I think it's not about replacing `b1` by `b2` but about replacing whitespace/tab/newline separated combinations of `b1` and `b2` by an underscore-separated combination.

Comment: i'd love to see if this is faster.  with python there's a trade-off between using the best algorithm and the fastest implementation.  leaving everything as a regexp and tight loop may be a case of "worse is better" as it leaves more in c.